# How to convert NSAttributedString to NSData?

Tags: objective-c, nsattributedstring, nspasteboard, osx-mavericks

I have an `NSAttributedString` that I want to write back into the pasteboard.

The *general* `NSPasteboard` has different types, the `NSAttributedString` **with attachments** does fit to `NSPasteboardTypeRTFD`

I know how to write into the pasteboard:

```
    NSData * __strong newContent = ... // how?
    NSPasteboard * __strong pboard = [NSPasteboard generalPasteboard];
    NSString * __strong type = NSPasteboardTypeRTFD;
    [pboard setData:newContent forType:type];
```

But how to convert from a given `NSAttributedString` two a **RTF NSData** (which should then fit the type readable by the pasteboard)?

Comment: `RTFDFromRange:documentAttributes:` maybe?

Comment: Can you give an example code with a range example for a complete `NSAttributedString`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with `RTFDFromRange:documentAttributes:`

```
NSAttributedString *text;
...
NSData *rtfd = [text RTFDFromRange:NSMakeRange(0, text.length)
                documentAttributes:nil];
```

Answer (score 2):

what do you want the data to be, do you just want the text?
 Then you can convert to an NSString with `-string`

Edit: I couldn't find the methods because they are in a category: [NSAttributedString Application Kit Additions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAttributedString_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAttributedString/RTFDFromRange%3adocumentAttributes%3a)

Thank to @CRD for pointing me there.

I think it is interesting that it states for `-RTFDFromRange:documentAttributes:` it states that the `documentAttributes` is a required dictionary, then it says:

> If there are no document-level attributes, dict can be nil.

The companion guide can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextAttributes/RTFAndAttrStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000164)

Comment: Everything what NSAttributedString could be, a styled text with image attachments for example